# How to access the template argument's own template arguments?

Tags: c++, class, templates, class-template

Say you have a class template (e.g. `second` below). Say that class template's template arguments are instantiations of another class template (e.g. `first` below). How do you access the template argument's own template arguments? Is that possible?

Here's some code:

```
template<size_t n>
class first {
};

template<typename instantiated_first>
class second {
    // would like to be able to access the "n"
    // of instantiated_first
};

int main() {
    second<first<3>> thing;

    return 0;
}
```

Three possibilities come to mind:

1. rewrite `first` to store `n` as a data member, or
2. redesign `second` to inherit from an instantiated class from `first`, and
3. ask for the exact same template arguments in both class templates.

I ask because I would rather not edit pre-existing code (option 1), and in my particular application, it doesn't really make sense (to me, at least) to think of `second` as being a type of `first` (option 2). I will be instantiating many objects of type `specialized_first`, and so it makes more sense for `second` to "own" these objects and store them in a container. Option 3 doesn't seem very stylish, either.

Are there any fancy template features that I don't know about to accomplish this in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more sensible way is not to store `n` as a data member but rather as `static constexpr size_t` so it doesn't allocate any additional runtime space. This is the standard and most flexible mechanism - allowing for various other templates to access this parameter without mush fuss. E.g., you can make a completely different version of `first` and allow your `second` to utilize the other version all the while supporting the original as long as all version satisfy the concept interface.

Similarly, every `typename T_` template parameter can be forwarded to users of the template via `using T = T_;`. In general, template parameters are inaccessible unless you allow them to be by declaring them to be types or storing their value as `constexpr` or otherwise.

You can remodel `second` so it accepts the same template parameter but it becomes harder the more other templates you have that use `first` and this value/type or when you suddenly want to use `second` for an alternative version of `first`. Better address such problems on the root. For example, in `std` all their template classes have all the necessary types declared inside the class in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a partial specialization and pick the arguments from there.

```
template<typename T>
class second<first<T>> {
    // T is available here for use.
};
```

Or even more generally do this

```
template<typename T, typename U
class second<U<T>> {
    // T is available here for use.
};
```

This will match all instantiations with one template argument.

Comment: Do note the OP has a non-type template parameter for `first`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the downside to this is that, when `U` has many template arguments, you have to keep asking for a long list of template arguments over and over again.

Comment: There are ways to match using variadic parameters. You'll need to study metaprogramming in more depth.